# Why is one of my files missing when using wine?

Tags: filesystems, wine

I have a directory with a collection of mp3 files. I plan to use a Windows program in wine on them, but one of the files -- `09.mp3` -- is "invisible" to wine.

The program I'm using ignores the file as though it doesn't exist. I ran `winefile` and `cmd` in wine, and they don't show the file either. The rest of the files in the dir exist.

### Facts

- The affected file was added years ago; the other files were added today
- All the files have the same owner (me)
- All the files have the same permissions (0644), and `getfacl` shows the same result for all files too
- `lsattr` shows the same results for all files: `--------------e------- 09.mp3`
- Renaming the file does not help
- Making a copy - The copy appears, unless I use `cp -a`
- ext4 filesystem, mounted with options rw,relatime
- Linux kernel 5.15.0-47-generic on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)

### `ls` output

```
> ls -l
total 133016K
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  6073826 2023-12-20 17:31:21 01.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  8667281 2023-12-20 17:31:22 02.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb 12242599 2023-12-20 17:31:22 03.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb 11234269 2023-12-20 17:31:23 04.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  7327289 2023-12-20 17:34:40 05.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb 11278180 2023-12-20 17:31:20 06.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  7795117 2023-12-20 17:34:41 07.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  8146473 2023-12-20 17:34:40 08.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  4772263 2021-08-04 11:16:35 09.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  8066202 2023-12-20 17:31:20 10.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  7778193 2023-12-20 17:34:41 11.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb 10224047 2023-12-20 17:34:42 12.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  9962763 2023-12-20 17:34:42 13.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb 12967837 2023-12-20 17:34:43 14.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mrb mrb  9644160 2023-12-20 17:31:24 15.mp3
```

### `dir /a` output

missing `09.mp3`:

```
> wine cmd /c dir /a
Volume in drive R has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000

Directory of R:\Album

20/12/2023   6:07 PM  <DIR>         .
20/12/2023   5:47 PM  <DIR>         ..
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     6,073,826  01.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     8,667,281  02.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM    12,242,599  03.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM    11,234,269  04.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     7,327,289  05.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM    11,278,180  06.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     7,795,117  07.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     8,146,473  08.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     8,066,202  10.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     7,778,193  11.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM    10,224,047  12.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     9,962,763  13.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM    12,967,837  14.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     9,644,160  15.mp3
      14 files              131,408,236 bytes
       2 directories    562,884,780,032 bytes free
```

## winfile

missing `09.mp3`:

[image: winfile showing folder with 09.mp3 missing]

Comment: I wonder if wine has a log somewhere, they should mention errors like that. I guess a `ls` with a different `--time` might've spotted it, but the default time just looks a little old... a good clue since it's the only visible difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file access time is in the future - the far-off year 2446:

```
> stat 09.mp3
  File: 09.mp3
  Size: 4772263     Blocks: 9328       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 313589982   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     mrb)   Gid: ( 1000/     mrb)
Access: 2446-05-10 19:38:55.000000000 -0300
Modify: 2021-08-04 11:16:35.905612900 -0300
Change: 2023-12-20 17:49:55.600681442 -0400
 Birth: 2022-09-30 19:00:34.856978234 -0300
```

Resetting it fixes the problem:

```
> touch -a 09.mp3

> stat 09.mp3
  File: 09.mp3
  Size: 4772263     Blocks: 9328       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 313589982   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     mrb)   Gid: ( 1000/     mrb)
Access: 2023-12-20 18:11:47.220986317 -0400
Modify: 2021-08-04 11:16:35.905612900 -0300
Change: 2023-12-20 18:11:47.220986317 -0400
 Birth: 2022-09-30 19:00:34.856978234 -0300

> wine cmd /c dir /a
Volume in drive R has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000

Directory of R:\Album

20/12/2023   6:07 PM  <DIR>         .
20/12/2023   5:47 PM  <DIR>         ..
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     6,073,826  01.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     8,667,281  02.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM    12,242,599  03.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM    11,234,269  04.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     7,327,289  05.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM    11,278,180  06.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     7,795,117  07.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     8,146,473  08.mp3
04/08/2021  10:16 AM     4,772,263  09.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     8,066,202  10.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     7,778,193  11.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM    10,224,047  12.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM     9,962,763  13.mp3
20/12/2023   5:34 PM    12,967,837  14.mp3
20/12/2023   5:31 PM     9,644,160  15.mp3
      15 files              136,180,499 bytes
       2 directories    562,884,780,032 bytes free
```

I don't know why a far-future access date is a problem for wine or Windows. The Win32 FILETIME structure can handle dates for thousands of years. Anyway it's easy to resolve for my affected file.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old outdated version of Wine.

This bug cannot be reproduced in newer Wine releases, specifically in 9.0-rc2:

[image: Wineconsole Wine 9.0-rc2]